# prev element is not returned

Tags: jquery

I am trying get the previous element. So when click in the `.percen` I want to alert the value of the previous element. At the moment I get `undefined`. What is the problem?

```
<input class="c currency" type="text" name="artigoAlternativo1_C"/>
<input class="d currency percen" type="text" name="artigoAlternativo1_D"/>

<br/>

<input class="c currency" type="text" name="artigoAlternativo1_C"/>
<input class="d currency percen" type="text" name="artigoAlternativo1_D"/>
```

```js
$.fn.percentageFormat = function () {
    this.each(function (i) {
        $(this).change(function (e) {
            var $curr = $(this);
            $curr_ = $curr.prev('.c');
            alert(this.value);
            alert($curr_.prev().value);
        });
    });
    return this;
}
$(function () {
    $('.percen').percentageFormat();
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZY5m4/1/)

Comment: @Adil, I don't think that's actually true; see here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the `prev` method twice and jQuery object has no `value` property, change:

```
alert($curr_.prev().value);
```

To:

```
alert($curr.prev().val());
```

or:

```
alert($curr_.val());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2gf95/

Comment: actually, it should be `$curr_.val()`. If he already defined `$curr_ = $curr.prev('.c');` there is no need to do that again.

Answer (score 3):

In your code `$curr_` is a jQuery element so you need to use `val()` to get the value. Also you are using `prev()` twice. Try this:

```
$.fn.percentageFormat = function () {
    this.each(function (i) {
        $(this).change(function (e) {
            var $curr = $(this);
            $curr_ = $curr.prev('.c');
            alert(this.value);
            alert($curr_.val()); // < Note no prev() here, and use of val()
        });
    });
    return this;
}
$(function () {
    $('.percen').percentageFormat();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZY5m4/3/)